# how to run exe file and type arguments from python

Tags: python, cmd, operating-system, exe, sys

I have an executable external program that ask the name of the arguments file.

I am trying to program this action through python coding. How can it be done?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to run exe file you can use:

```
import os
path = "exe-file-path.exe"
os.system("start " + path)
```

os library is built-in (both python 2,3)

Comment: but how to input the argument?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, the software is asking to type another file that contains parameters, how do i set up that file name in python code

Answer (score 0):

You must use `sys` and `os` module and here is sample code:

```
import sys
import os

if sys.argv[1] == "something":
    # Do something
```

Remember that `sys.argv[0]` is script itself and `sys.argv[1]` is first argument like `example.py first_argument`. If first argument can be other things [and other arguments if available], just add more variants.
If it has more arguments, just add `elif sys.argv[%next number%] == "something":
        # Do something`.
And also replace `# Do something` with valid command to do when that argument is choosen.

Comment: Don't forget that this must be runned from CMD [On Windows] or Bash [On Unix, also called Linux systems]!